# C#, distribution list and ACLs

Tags: c#, acl

I am working on a little desktop app which create and manage repository on a Windows server.
I have two problems:

=> I don't find how to apply on folders some ACLs for an active directory group. When i use

```
addAccessRule(identity, fsRight, AccessCtrlType);
```

I have a `IdentityNotMapedExecption...` How can I apply some security rules for a group in C# ?

=> When I create a universal distribution group like this :

```
group.Properties["groupType"].Value = 0x8;

group.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "GRP_DIF_" + projectName + "-MOE";

group.Properties["displayName"].Value = "GRP_DIF_" + projectName + "-MOE";

group.Properties["mail"].Value = projectName + "-MOE@domain.com";

group.Properties["mailNickname"].Value = projectName + "-MOE";

group.Properties["managedBy"].Value = MDN;

group.CommitChanges();

group.Close();
```

The group is "correctly" created but is non-functional. I know forgetting really important thing but I don't know which one...

Comment: It's better to add your full code when adding access rule on this `addAccessRule(identity, fsRight, AccessCtrlType);`